# Binary Tree Inorder Traversal - Recursive

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

Wrote below solution to a leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/-

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode],traversal_list = []) -> List[int]:

        if root:
            traversal_list= self.inorderTraversal(root.left,traversal_list)
            traversal_list.append(root.val)
            traversal_list = self.inorderTraversal(root.right, traversal_list)
        return traversal_list
```

Returns correct solution of [1,3,2] from example question #1.
Returns [1,3,2] AGAIN from example question #2: [ ].

Why is answer #1 getting carried over to question #2?

Comment: Do you save the output of the first call to a variable called `traversal_list`? it can be related to the scopes and the same list variable accessed from different functions. How are you calling the method `inorderTraversal` from outside?

Comment: Many have fallen for this particular behaviour of default parameters in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**don't modify a parameter's default value**

The template provided by LeetCode -

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
```

The problem with your code is here -

1. You added a third parameter, `traversal_list`, with a default value of `[]`
2. In the non-recursive branch of the code, a reference to this list is returned
3. In the recursive branch, `traversal_list` is mutated with `.append`

```py
class Solution:
    # ⚠️ 1
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode],traversal_list = []) -> List[int]:
        if root:
            traversal_list= self.inorderTraversal(root.left,traversal_list)
            traversal_list.append(root.val) # ⚠️ 3
            traversal_list = self.inorderTraversal(root.right, traversal_list)
        return traversal_list # ⚠️ 2
```

**recreation of the problem**

This means subsequent calls to `Solution#inorderTraversal` will contain a prepopulated `traversal_list` and result in an incorrect answer. You can see a minimal recreation of the problem in below -

```py
def foo (x = []):
  x.append(1)
  return x
```

```py
print(foo()) # [1]
print(foo()) # [1, 1] # ❌
```

In another example, look how the default parameter value is evaluated **only once** when the script is executed -

```py
def hello():
  print(1)
  return 3

def foo (x = hello()):  # ⚠️ hello() happens first
  return x

print(2)                # ⚠️ this is actually second!
print(foo())
```

```py
1
2
3
```

**fix it**

To fix it, remove the third parameter, `traversal_list`. There's no need for it. Simply return `[]` when `root` is not present -

```py
class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
        if root:
            left = self.inorderTraversal(root.left)
            right = self.inorderTraversal(root.right)
            return left + [root.val] + right # ✅
        else:
            return [] # ✅
```

An improved way to write this is to write a traversal function outside of the class -

```py
def inorder(t):
  if t:
    yield from inorder(t.left)  # ⚙️
    yield t.val                 # 
    yield from inorder(t.right) # ⚙️
```

```py
class Solution:
  def inorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
    return list(inorder(root)) #
```

**"what if i want to use append?"**

If you absolutely want to use `.append`, you can model the solution above in a similar way.

```py
def inorder(root):
  output = [] # 
  def traverse(t):
    if t:
      traverse(t.left)     # ⚙️
      output.append(t.val) #  + 
      traverse(t.right)    # ⚙️
  traverse(root)
  return output #
```

```py
class Solution:
  def inorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
    return inorder(root) #
```

**not a universal behavior**

Note this behaviour is in direct contrast to other languages. For example, JavaScript will re-evaluate a parameter's default value each time the function is run -

```js
function foo(x = []) {
  x.push(1)
  return x
}

console.log(foo()) // [1]
console.log(foo()) // [1]  differs from python's behaviour
```

```js
function hello() {
  console.log(1)
  return 3
}

function foo(x = hello()) {
  return x
}

console.log(2)
console.log(foo())
```

```js
2
1  //  differs from python's behaviour
3
```

Comment: Interesting.  So the argument's default value is the same object on every call, not a fresh one?  I had no idea.  Has this always been the case?

Comment: @JohnBollinger that is correct. I added another example that shows default values are executed **only once** when a script is evaluated.